# Find % according to values in one column (Need to add iteration loop) in php

Tags: php

I want to update 3rd column according to values based in 2nd column. Right to now I could print % value only for 1st team correctly. Other teams have wrong values.
Any help please.
[image: html table]

```
echo "<table border="."1"."align="."right".">
    <tr>
        <th align="."center".">ID</th>
        <th>Internal Team Names</th>            
        <th width="."10px"." >Passed % for aw34_0530_tc1015</th>

    </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['TeamInternalNames'] . "</td>";

            $TotalTestsForTeam = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * from aw34_0530_tc1015 where Application="."'".$application_l."'"); //rows for ace application
            $TotalTestsForTeamCount = $TotalTestsForTeam->num_rows; //rows for ace application

            $PassedTestsForTeam_query= "SELECT * from aw34_0530_tc1015 where Result='passed' AND Application='".$row['TeamInternalNames']."'"; //ace passed count
            $passed = mysqli_query($conn ,$PassedTestsForTeam_query);
            $TotalPaassedTestsForTeam = $passed->num_rows; //rows for ace application
            //echo "Count of passed ace in aw34_0530_tc1015 = TotalPaassedTestsForTeam Results "; //rows for ace application
            $passed_percentForTEam = ($TotalPaassedTestsForTeam/$TotalTestsForTeamCount)*100 | 0;

        echo "<td>" . $passed_percentForTEam . "</td>";


        // if ($row['Result'] == "passed") {
            // echo "<td style="."background-color:#33FF38".">P</td>";
        // } else {
            // echo "<td style="."background-color:#FF334C".">F</td>";
            // }

        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Too little data to understand.
Try to output `$TotalPaassedTestsForTeam` and `$TotalTestsForTeamCount` variables to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Had tried to print values for $TotalPassedTestsForTeam and found that it's printing 336 for all teams and that is why %, for other except first one, is wrong.